# Angular 2 Error trying to diff '3' when trying to add element to array

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

list.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../model/todo';
import { TodoDetailComponent } from './detail.component';
import { TodoService } from '../service/todo.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-todos',
    styleUrls: ['/app/todo/styles/list.css'],
    templateUrl:'/app/todo/templates/list.html',
    directives: [[TodoDetailComponent]],
    providers: []
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    public todos: Todo[];
    title = 'List of Todos';
    selectedTodo: Todo;
    newTodo: string;

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getTodos();
    }
    addTodo() {
        this.todoService.addTodo(this.newTodo).then(
            todos => this.todos = todos
        );
    }
    getTodos() {
        TodoService.getTodos().then(
            todos => this.todos = todos
        );
    }
    onSelect(todo: Todo) {
        this.selectedTodo = todo;
    }
}
```

todo.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from '../model/todo';
import { TODOS } from './mock-todos';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
    static getTodos() {
        return Promise.resolve(TODOS).then(
            todos => todos
        );
    }
    getTodo(id: number) {
        return Promise.resolve(TODOS).then(
            todos => todos.filter(todo => todo.id === id)[0]
        );
    }
    addTodo(task: string) {
        return Promise.resolve(TODOS).then(
            todos => todos.push(new Todo(TODOS.length+1, task))
        );
    }
}
```

I get this error when calling `addTodo()` from the component:

[image: Angular 2 Error trying to diff '3' when trying to add element to array]

I have gone over it several time and still have no clue what's going on.

Here's the definition of `TODOS`:

```
import { Todo } from '../model/todo';

export var TODOS: Todo[] = [
    { id: 1, task: 'Do something' },
    { id: 2, task: 'Do something else' }
];
```

I have a button that triggers the `addTodo()` in the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular uses that diffchecker **whenever the list changes its values** - to verify the items the list had and what items were added to it.

The error happens because you probably are trying to iterate over (using  `*ngFor`, for instance) the number `3`, something that is not a collection.

In other words, from the error message, your variable that should be a collection is the value `3`.

## Your case

Since the exception is thrown when you call `ListComponent#addTodo()`:

```
public todos: Todo[];
...
addTodo() {
    this.todoService.addTodo(this.newTodo).then(
        todos => this.todos = todos
    );
}
```

You are probably assigning the value `3` to `this.todos` at `todos => this.todos = todos`.

Knowing the above, we have to find out why your service is returning `3` as result of a call to its `addTodo()`.

Taking a look at `TodoService#addTodo()`:

```
addTodo(task: string) {
    return Promise.resolve(TODOS).then(
        todos => todos.push(new Todo(TODOS.length+1, task))
    );
}
```

You'll notice that the method is actually returning the result of the `push()` - which is the length of the array after the push. And since it adds one element to the `TODOS` mock array, it will have three elements after the push, thus returning `3`.

## Fix

To make it all work, assign a collection to the variable used at the `*ngFor`, not the number `3`.

In your case, since the value assigned to it is the one returned by the service, simply make it return the array:

```
addTodo(task: string) {
    return Promise.resolve(TODOS).then(
        todos => {
          todos.push(new Todo(TODOS.length+1, task));
          return todos;                                  /// ------------- added this line
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Great answer!! I assumed .push would return the new array.

Comment: Updated the code as suggested and it worked as intended.